# Using QT with custom UI/Graphic subsystem

Tags: linux, qt, qnx

We have an custom UI framework which sits over QNX Screen or Linux Weston/wayland framework. This is to bring in platform independent API to application software.
So I wanted to know how/where do I replace QNX screen in QT with our custom library so that for eg. any window creation and etc.. calls will be passed through our custom framework.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Platform Abstraction is what you are looking for. It's going to be a bit of work to implement and maintain with Qt updates. To get started, experiment on a desktop PC  with the "minimal" plugin.

Docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpa.html